# how to assign java.util.LinkedHashMap<*, *> to kotlin.collections.Map<*, *>

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

I have declared a method which takes map as parameter:

```
fun myKotlinMethod(myParameter:Map<String,String>)...
```

Later I read data from json. I get an object of type: `java.util.LinkedHashMap<*, *>` I need to use reflection to invoke `myKotlinMethod`. Before that, I test if the value is assignable to `myParameter`. I ask parameter type using kotlin reflection and I get `kotlin.collections.Map<*, *>`.

bottom line is that `java.util.LinkedHashMap<*, *>` does not implement `kotlin.collections.Map<*, *>` (it cannot) and therefore is not assignable.

I'm using this method to check assignability

```
inline fun isAssignable(parameterType: KType, valueType: KType): Boolean {
    if (parameterType == valueType) return true
    return parameterType.isSubtypeOf(valueType)
}
```

and I test like

```
if (isAssignable(parameter.type.classifier!!.starProjectedType, parameterValue::class.starProjectedType))
```

I read about some dark magic kotlin does to collection during compile time, but during runtime, java classes should be used. This is not my case since I get kotlin classes in runtime.

So, How do I correctly check for collection types compatibility?

Comment: Did you mean to check `parameterType.isSupertypeOf(valueType)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have written this the other way around:

```
// you can even delete the parameterType == valueType check
// isSubtypeOf returns true if the types are the same
return parameterType.isSubtypeOf(valueType)
```

The method call is valid if the type of the value is a subtype of the parameter type, so it should be:

```
return valueType.isSubtypeOf(parameterType)
```

However, note that this is not safe at all. Since you only know that the value is a `LinkedHashMap<*, *>`, what if the map has `Int`s, `Double`s, or `UUID`s in it? That would still pass the subtype check. Because you used `starProjectedType` on the parameter type, you threw away the `<String, String>` part of the type, and didn't actually check that the value actually only has strings.

To make sure that the collections are compatible, you should also check the collection's elements:

```
fun isAssignableToMapStringString(value: Any) =
    if (value is Map<*, *>) {
        value.all { it.value is String && it.key is String }
    } else {
        false
    }
```

It can be quite hard to generalise this to any `KType` though. You'd have to do a lot of reflection to get the elements out of the collection. And you'd have to handle maps and collections separately, since `Map` and `Collection` are unrelated interfaces :(